# How do I make document side script conditional?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm having trouble breaking my horizontal scroll when the viewport is 480px or below.  My scroll has this document-side script:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#wrapper").wrapInner("<table><tr>");
            $(".post").wrap("<td>");
        });
        $(function () {
            $("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
                this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I remove the table wrapping feature then the scroll breaks.  Instead I'm hoping for one of these two possible fixes:

1. a media query command that forces the removal of a class(es) so I can then display as a block.
2. a way to make the above document-side code conditional on viewport size.

Thanks in advance.  I know its not the neatest, but its the only way I was able to get the scroll to work (except on IE)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to only horizontally scroll if `body` is more than 480px wide:

```
        $("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
            var $this = $(this); // 'body' in this case
            var widthLimit = 480;
            if ($this.width() > widthLimit) {
                // horizontal scroll
                this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Here is the media query that will display `#wrapper` as a block if the viewport is less than 480px:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #wrapper {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Note that media queries can generally only change styling and not add or remove `classes` or `id`s.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't break it at all.  Looks fine on desktop/wide devices, but the second you hit 480 totally gets screwed up.  Is there a way to add a conditional to the script so that at 480 or less it turns off?